# Let $f$ be real function that admits an antiderivative $F$ and $F(x)>0$ for every $x$ real

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f$ be real function that admits an antiderivative $F$ and $F(x)>0$ for every $x$ real . Prove that for any $e>0$ there exists $x_e$ such that $|f(x)|<e$

I stuck to find connection between hypothesis and question that we have to find

Answer (score 0):

> I stuck to find connection between hypothesis and question that we have to find

You're given a function $f$ with an antiderivative $F$. In other words, $F' = f$ (presumably this means that we require $F$ to be differentiable everywhere<sup>1</sup>). So removing $f$ from the question entirely, they are actually asking you to show that $F'$ is (close to) $0$ somewhere, assuming that $F$ is strictly positive everywhere.

---

<sup>1</sup>If we don't require that $F$ is differentiable everywhere, you get cases like $$f(x) = \cases{-1 & if $x<0$\\1& otherwise}$$ with $F(x) = |x| + 1$ as  possible antideirvative. Then the statement clearly doesn't hold.

Comment: I'd not call $x \mapsto |x|+1$ the antiderivative of your $f$ function (at least not on an interval $I$ with $0 \in I$, because it's not even Darboux there), just an integral function.

Comment: @Botond I wouldn't either. The point of my example was entirely to demonstrate why it's reasonable to assume just from the context of the problem itself that $F$ is differentiable everywhere: because otherwise the statement we are asked to prove is false.

Answer (score 0):

I will assume that $F'(x)$ exists for every $x$ and $F'(x)=f(x)$. Suppose there exists $e>0$ such that $|f(x)|\geq e$ for every $x$. By IVP for derivatives it follows that either $f(x) \geq e$ for all $x$ or $f(x) \leq -e$ for all $x$. In the first case, using MVT,  $F(0)-F(x)\geq e(-x)$ for all $x<0$. Be letting $x \to -\infty$ we get a contradiction to the fact that $F(x) >0$ for all $x$. A similar argument works for the other case.